# Select an option on a Select tag and keep it there on reload/refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make a `Select` tag in where after you choose and click an `option` from it, it will load to the `href` value that the `option` tag has. And after loading the `option` that you've selected will be the one highlighted on the `select` tag.

so far, from what I have searched I only have:

html:

```
    <select id="jumpid" onchange="jump(this)" >
        <option value="index.php?ID=1">Val 1</option>
        <option value="index.php?ID=2">Val 2</option>
        <option value="index.php?ID=3">Val 3</option>
        <option value="index.php?ID=4">Val 4</option>
        <option value="index.php?ID=5">Val 5</option>
        <option value="index.php?ID=6">Val 6</option>
        <option value="index.php?ID=7">Val 7</option>
    </select>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    function jump(selectedLink){
    var chpSelect = selectedLink.value;
    location.href=document.getElementById("jumpid").value;
}
</script>
```

When I select something for example `Val 3`, the browser will reload to `index.php?ID=3` and it's contents. But the `select` tag still shows `Val 1`, I want it to stay to `Val 3`.

Comment: So you should add `selected="selected"` depending on ID.

Comment: onload you could parse url and load id in select
https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's crude but it'll work:

```
<?php
$id=0;
if(isset($_GET['ID']){
    $id = $_GET['ID'];
}
?>   

 <select id="jumpid" onchange="jump(this)" >
        <option value="index.php?ID=1" <?php if($id==1){echo "selected";}?>>Val 1</option>
        <option value="index.php?ID=2" <?php if($id==2){echo "selected";}?>>Val 2</option>
        <option value="index.php?ID=3" <?php if($id==3){echo "selected";}?>>Val 3</option>
        <option value="index.php?ID=4" <?php if($id==4){echo "selected";}?>>Val 4</option>
        <option value="index.php?ID=5" <?php if($id==5){echo "selected";}?>>Val 5</option>
        <option value="index.php?ID=6" <?php if($id==6){echo "selected";}?>>Val 6</option>
        <option value="index.php?ID=7" <?php if($id==7){echo "selected";}?>>Val 7</option>
    </select>
```